# Support of Convolution and Smoothing

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, convolution, regularization

[image]

[image]

I just want to know how it follows that $v^{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}(\bar{V})$? I could see how $v^{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}(V)$ by using the translations, but I'm having difficulty seeing how it extends to $\bar{V}$, since it says that $u_{\epsilon}(x) := u(x^{\epsilon}) \text{ for } x \text{ in } V$, we are mollifying on $V$. I also don't think we can use the same type of extension as in the previous question I asked, since previously we extended a function that had already become zero to zero on the rest of the domain. Do you have any idea of how this follows? Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator \supp {supp}$For functions on $\mathbb R^n$ we have in general $\supp (f*g) \subset \supp f+\supp g$, where $A+B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$. To see this note that $x$ must be in this set for $f(x-y)g(y)$ to be non-zero.

Thus we have $\supp f^\epsilon \subset \supp f + B(0,\epsilon) = \{x \mid d(x,\supp f)<\epsilon\}$, so $\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} \supp f^\epsilon \subset \supp f$ (which I guess is what you were trying to get at with your "limit').

Intuitively we expect $\supp f \subset \supp f^\epsilon$, and this is true if $\eta(0)>0, \eta\ge 0, f \ge 0$. (I'm assuming $\eta$ is at least continuous here; usually we take it to be smooth.) In general, however, I do not think this always holds.

The only time we would have $\supp f ^\epsilon \subset \supp f$ is when $\supp f$ is the whole space: there will always be some "leakage" of $f^\epsilon$ over the boundary of $\supp f$.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful response. Would you be able to look at the additional question regarding an approximation proof for Sobolev Spaces found in Lawrence Evans book 'Partial Differential Equations' I'm not sure if there is an option on this forum to attach the relevant pages of the document but I will try.

Comment: @Byron: For your first additional question: you need $W^{k,p}$ convergence, not just $L^p$; however, this is exactly what Evans established in the previous subchapter ($W^{k,p}$ convergence of mollifier to function on any $V \subset \subset U$).

Comment: @Byron: You don't really need to worry about defining a $W_0$ - a finite number of terms plus $u^0$ is a finite number of terms. Your compactness argument isn't quite right - just because there is a finite subcover of $V$ by the $W_i$ doesn't mean we can throw away other terms from the sum. You should really be applying a compactness argument to the increasing sequence $U_i$  to show that $V$ is contained in some $U_k$, and thus that $V$ only intersects finitely many $W_i$. The $u^i$ contributing to the sum in $V$ are then those corresponding to this finite set of $W_i$, and possibly $u^0$.

Comment: Okay so just to confirm take $x \in U$ then we can find $V \subset \subset U$ such that $x \in V$. $\{U_{i}\}_{i}$ covers $U$ so it follows that $\{U_{i}\}_{i}^{\infty}$ covers $V$ and since $V \subset \subset U$ it follows that there is a finite subcover, but $\{U_{i}\}_{i}$ is an increasing sequence so there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $V \subset U_{k}$ so $V \subset \cup_{i=1}^{k}U$. It follows then that $V$ only intersects finitely many $W_{i}$'s. Then as you said the $u^{i}$'s contributing to the sum in $V$ are those corresponding to finite set of $W_{i}$ and possibly $u_{0}$.

Comment: Could you please explain the following: How do we know that $u^{i} \in W^{k,p}(U)$ in (3)? By previous results in Lawrence I can see why $u^{i} \in W^{k,p}(V)$ and how can find $\epsilon_{i} \rightarrow 0$ small enough such that $||u^{i} - \zeta_{i}u||_{W^{k,p}(V)} \leq \frac{\delta}{2^{i+1}}$ for $i = 0,1,...$ since $V \subset \subset U$. But how do we know that $u^{i} \in W^{k,p}(U)$ and how do we use the previous result you mentioned: $u^{\epsilon} \rightarrow u$ in $W_{\text{loc}}^{k,p}$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ to state $||u^{i} - \zeta_{i}u||_{W^{k,p}(U)} \leq \frac{\delta}{2^{i+1}}$?

Comment: By construction $\zeta_i u$ and $u^i$ are supported in $W_i \subset \subset U$. The local approximation theorem tells us that $\Vert u^i - \zeta_i u \Vert_{W^{k,p} (V)} \to 0$ for any $V \subset \subset U$ - so just take $V = W_i$ here. Since the function is supported inside $W_i$ its norm over $W_i$ is exactly its norm over $U$.

Comment: Thanks Yes I understand that, but isn't it at least required that $u^{i}$ is defined on all of $U$? From what I understand based on Appendix C page 629 Lawrence , $u^{i} := \eta_{\epsilon_{i}}\ast(\zeta_{i}u)$ in $U_{\epsilon}$ if $\zeta_{i}u : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  where $U_{\epsilon} := \{ x \in U : \text{dist}(x, \partial U) > \epsilon\}$. So $u^{i}$ is not defined on all of $U$.

Comment: @Alex: in general the mollification is only defined on a shrinking of the original domain - however, in this case we are taking the mollification of $\zeta_i u$, which is defined on all of $U$ but zero outside $V_i \subset \subset U$. Thus for small enough $\epsilon_i$ the mollification is in fact compactly supported on $U$.

Comment: Okay so then starting with the general idea, is the following fine: $\zeta_{i}u$ is compactly supported on $V_{i} \subset \subset U$ and therefore we know that for small enough $\epsilon_{i}$ we have a mollification $u^{i}$ which is compactly supported on some $W_{i}$ such that $V_{i}$ $\subset$ $W_{i}$ $\subset$ $U_{\epsilon}$ $\subset U$ . We then extend $u^{i}$ by saying that $u^{i} = 0$ on $U / U_{\epsilon}$ and we have $u^{i}$ compactly supported on $U$. Is that fine? Or is there no need for that type of extension? Thanks, I just want to confirm that I have the right idea.

Comment: @Alex: yup, that's the idea.

Comment: Could you please assist with one last question on approximation theorems for Sobolev Spaces in Lawrence. I added at the top.

Comment: Please don't destroy your previous question to ask a new one.

Comment: Okay no problem.

Comment: In the initial question you said that intuitively $\text{supp}f \subset \text {supp}f^{\epsilon}$ and the only time $\text{supp}f^{\epsilon} \subset \text{supp}f$ is when $\text{supp}f$ is the whole space. But take locally integrable function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, if in the ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ the only point for which $f(y)$ is non-zero is when $x=y$ then it follows that $x \in \text{supp}f$ but $x \notin \text{supp}f^{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Alex: you need to use the $L^p$ (i.e. null-set-invariant) version of support. Since $f = 0$ a.e., it has empty support.

Comment: Okay I see how that follows since $f$ is only non-zero for a finite number of points in my example. I was assuming that the usual definition of support was still valid. What text would you advise I read for a full description of this? Not getting any good results from a web search.

Comment: @Alex: It's Prop 4.17 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis* - the discussion is not very long but it's pretty simple really. I'm not sure whether Evans bothers defining the support - it might be in one of the appendices.